# executing multimatch ElasticSearch with boolean operations in query

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Can I execute multimatch search with ElasticSearch and NEST in a way I can pass query with boolean operations inside the query? It appears all terms I passed to multimatch are by default linked with OR (which can be changed to other operator).

I'd like ES to evaluate boolean operators from the query, ex. "A && B || C" and the same search multiple fields.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html#operator-min

```
{
  "multi_match" : {
    "query":      "Will Smith",
    "type":       "best_fields",
    "fields":     [ "first_name", "last_name" ],
    "operator":   "and" 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set the [`operator` to `and`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html#operator-min) to change the semantics of a [`multi_match` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html). As an example with NEST

```cs
void Main()
{
    var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));
    var connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings(pool);

    var client = new ElasticClient(connectionSettings);

    client.Search<MyDocument>(s => s
        .Query (q => q
            .MultiMatch(m => m
                .Fields(f => f
                    .Field(p => p.FirstProperty)
                    .Field(p => p.SecondProperty)
                )
                .Query("this is the query")
                .Operator(Operator.And)
            )
        )
    );
}

public class MyDocument
{
    public string FirstProperty { get; set; }

    public string SecondProperty { get; set; }
}
```

produces the following query

```
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "this is the query",
      "operator": "and",
      "fields": [
        "firstProperty",
        "secondProperty"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Also take a look at the [`MultiMatch` query usage docs for NEST](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/2.x/multi-match-usage.html).